# how to display a text in homepage onAfterInitialise() in joomla 3x

Tags: php, joomla

I've just started learning Joomla. Please advise how to make use of `onAfterInitialise()` event.I just want to see how things work through Joomla plugin. For now I just want to display 'Some text' in home page or in all pages when **page loaded** with this plugin.

With the help of some tutorials online, I've created plugin as following and installed and activated it. Just don't know how to make use of it!

XML file `chat.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="System">
    <name>Chat</name>
    <author>Apple</author>
    <creationDate>November 2005</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2016 mysite.com.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>apple@mysite.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.mysite.com</authorUrl>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <description>This is a chatting plugin</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="categories">chat.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

PHP file `chat.php`

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );  

class plgSystemChat extends JPlugin
{

    public function __construct(&$subject, $config)  
    {  
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);  

    }  

    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

     function onAfterInitialise()
     {
        echo "<h1>test plgContentConversekit</h1>";
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

And `index.html` with following code in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>
```

Comment: are you coming from wordpress background?? Plugins in wordpress are different then plugins in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make use of onAfterInitialise(). Below I used it to add script and stylesheet on page load.

```
function onAfterInitialise() {

         // Load Bootstrap
        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
        JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(). "plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit.css");
        $document->addScript("plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit.js", "text/javascript", false,  false);

        return true;
    }
```